# How to rotate each instance individually based on its index in the list?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can rotate instances by a specific amount. What I can't figure it out, is the way to rotate each instance, around its own normal with a specific amount for its rotation. I want to rotate each cube in this example by 5 degrees, this means, the first index(0) should have rotation = 0, and index(1), should have a rotation amount of 5, and so on.
This rotation only happens around instance normal, or local axis.
I don't know how to create a for loop in the Geometry node and for each instance apply something like (i + 5 degree).
I appreciate any help here.

[image].

And here is the example that I tried to incorporate index:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the following after Instance on Points: Index * Angle (in radians!) -> Rotate Instances (Local Space)

Comment: @quellenform thanks for that. I updated my question with another screenshot and tried to follow what you explained. It doesn't work as I expected. Did I follow your instruction correctly, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mehr: you just added 1 to index. That's why quellenform wrote: in radians. And he wrote: multiply. Degree go from 0 to 360, but radians from 0 to 2*pi. Maybe read here about radians: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian and i am pretty sure you don't want to rotate all axis by your angle, so you should plug in a combine xyz node before plugging it into rotation.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, I tried multiplying as well and used a radiant value of 2*pi . For some reason, I can't manage to rotate each instance around their local X-axis. Please refer to the last image I just uploaded.

Comment: Divide 2*pi first by 55: index*(2pi/55). ...i will soon post the answer

Comment: @Mehr: Please don't get this wrong, just understand it as what i am writing: You either didn't read or understood the link about radians i sent you. To get good results in GN you have to understand some basic math principles. I am sure you would agree that you have to know add and multiply. And the same is true for the calculation of degrees to radians and back. If you don't understand that you won't make it further than just some basic GN results. So try to understand it and you will open new horizons for yourself. Just using the answer is not understanding it...just a hint from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way might be to simply use a curve created with `Curve Circle` as a base and convert it into points. This way you get the necessary rotation as a starting point.

The circle is best created with a defined number of points, and if you divide $2\pi$ by this number of points, you get an angle that you can multiply directly with your index.

If you then combine the previously obtained rotation with this calculated angle in the node `Rotate Euler` (*Local*), you will get exactly the rotation you are looking for for your instances.

[image]
<sub>PS: I've hidden the sockets/options here to save space, in case you're wondering where the inputs/outputs went.</sub>

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mehr You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here I found it. Multiply the index with the degrees you wanted in the y-axis

Hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: Tip: The `Math` node has its own option called *To Radians*.

Comment: Thanks, Muzammil, your solution works as well. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, I never look at that.